# Fixed width is affecting li display. Looking for a more elegant solution

Tags: html, css

I have set the width of content to 1045 which caused some strange behavior to li. Basically, if 2 li will fit in 1 line, it does not create a new line. I have found the crude solution to set li style="width:1000px;" to force create a new line, but I kept thinking to myself that there must be a more elegant way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Thank you all for the answers. I researched on Display and now I realize I have css setting all li to inline-block. I will set them to list-item. That should do the trick.

Comment: You need to add your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: set `width:100%;display:block;` instead of `width:1000px;`

Comment: make the width of `li` to 49%

Comment: @Patrick Mlr, thank you for the link. I'll have a read before my next question. Thank you guys for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the display to block on the li elements.

```
li { display: block; }
```